# Auto resizing RAM drive for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ramdisk

Is there a method or a tool that would allow me to have a RAM disk with dynamic memory allocation?

I want it to use RAM space only when space is actually used by files, I do not want an empty RAM drive of 2GB to waste 2GB of RAM immediately after initialization.

It would also be nicer if the RAM disk would decrease RAM usage upon deletion of files, but I know that I could be asking for too much.

Comment: @techie007 searched didn't find anything useful, currently using dataram ramdisk, -- I do not think this kind of question (What have you tried) is suitable here, since I am not asking how to code it from scratch.

Comment: It's basically a shopping/software recommendation question otherwise. Which are considered off-topic.

Comment: @techie007 it is not a shopping question if the answer is a 'method' to do it with any of the existing software.

Answer (score -1):

[SuperSpeed Product Suite / Desktops](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/productsuite.php)

[image: SuperSpeed Product Suite / Desktops comparison]

[RamDisk 11 for Desktop Systems](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/ramdisk.php)

[image: RamDisk 11 for Desktop Systems Product Comparison]

If I understand you need -

## Support for Virtual and Removable RamDisks.

See RamDisk Plus and SuperCache Express 5 for Desktop Systems.

[SuperCache Express 5 for Desktop Systems](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php)

[image: SuperCache Express 5 Desktop]